# Javascript setInterval function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a page where it shows users posts and refreshes automatically using the jQuery setInterval function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function() {
      $('#content').load('test.php');
}, 5000);
});
```

But the problem is I am going to have to create a duplicate page called test.php containing the same content which will be called every 5 seconds. I don't want people just viewing the source and finding the page with all the data on.

For example this site has a recent forum topics page which updates every couple of seconds,
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d4o0n2e0

I look in the page source and find the link to the page and this is what I find
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a2o0n691

I don't want people to be able to find that...

Is there a better way round this jQuery function? E.g. calling a php function to just run the query which will be in the test.php file?

Comment: Just of Note setInterval() is not a jQuery function but native to JavaScript

Comment: No matter what, people will be able to 'find the page with the data on it.' You can't hide anything on the web.

Comment: @Frank, I suppose this question does not have anything to do with SQL or database so I've removed the SQL tag.

Comment: I've update my topic with some screen shot examples

Comment: Per @BNL - you're retrieving that resource with a script already. The data is available in the browser. It shouldn't matter if they can see that URL or not; the PHP resource itself should implement any security measures you deem fit (sessions, for example).

Comment: It's just I only want them to access the data on the page I have the Javascript on, not on the page it's calling.

Comment: You could hash your url with a md5() and salt it with a secret key

Comment: @Frank, You can't hide it.  Download this and take a look for yourself:  http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/  Or, just use the debugging tools available in your browser.

Comment: @chchrist That doesn't make any sense. What will that do for him, except render his URL unusable?

Comment: Is your actual question "How do I hide a URL from the user?" If so, please remove all the irrelevant `setInterval` stuff, because as it stands the first *half* of your question seems to be completely unrelated to the question you finally ask. At least update the title.

Comment: @meagar he can't hide it but he can hash it in order to be unusable from other but usable from him as he can decryot it server side

Answer (score 3):

Thinking about security by thinking where the data is going isn't quite right.  Instead think about *who* has access to it.  If you don't serve that data from the PHP to someone who shouldn't see it in the first place, then it doesn't really matter how they view it.

So your `test.php` needs to have security around it that hooks into your authentication.  In psuedocode:

```
if (current user is authorized)
  send data
else
  403 Access Forbidden
```

Security through obscurity will only hurt you in the long run.  Even if you could obscure the location of that data, it leaves open the possibility that someone may find it eventually.  So do the security on the backend, out of reach of hackers, instead.